# How to get the proper position for eps graphs using dvipdfm?

Tags: miktex, eps, dvipdf

After a MikTeX update in the middle of October, the dvipdfm utility does not put eps graphs to correct place. The graphs are shifted with respect to their captions, parts of graphs may disappear. The same happened on computers of my colleagues after MikTeX updates.

I am working with MikTeX 2.9 under Windows 7.

The conversion through dvips and ps2pdf works normally.

Does anybody know what could be done with dvipdfm?

Here is a sample code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\title{Minimum example}
\author{S. O. Mebody}
\maketitle

Just some text. 

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{cp.eps}
  \caption{Sketch of something.}
  \label{fig:surfaces}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The graph appears below the page number in the `pdf` file generated by `dvipdfm` in MikTeX:
[image: Image of the pdf file produced with dvipdfm in MikTeX]

The figure is positioned normally in the dvi file.

The `dvipdfm` utility in TeXLive (on another computer) generates normal `pdf` file:

[image: Image of the pdf file produced with dvipdfm in TeXLive]

I do not know if this is important, but to generate eps files, I use printer drivers in eps mode, for example, a Tektronics Phaser 750P driver.

Because the utilities dvipdfm and dvipdfmx do not differ in this respect, I would assume that the problem is in some common configuration file. Another assumption is that something was wrong when dvipdfm and dvipdfmx were compiled from source. The dvipdfm utility in TeXLive works normally.

I do not observe this behavior on my laptop, where MikTeX 2.9 is outdated with the following packaging dates: miktex-dvipdfm-base-2.7 packaged on 2007-08-23, miktex-dvipdfmx-base-2.7 packaged on 2009-07-08, miktex-dvipdfmx-bin-2.9 packaged on 2012-06-11.

The packaging dates on the computer where wrong behavior is observed are as follows: miktex-dvipdfm-base-2.7 2007-08-23; miktex-dvipdfmx-base-2.7 packaged on 2013-06-18, miktex-dvipdfmx-bin-2.9 packaged on 2013-06-23.

Comment: A minimal example is always nice.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Can you make the `eps` file public?

Comment: @masu : How can I do it? It is too large (103 kB) to include it as text.

Comment: @user41247 may be using any Cloud storage services like dropbox/googledrive/skydrive

Comment: I just confirmed that I am seeing this same behavior. On both my Windows 7 desktop and a number of Windows Server virtual machines that I run. Both environments are running the most current MikTex with all updates from the mirrors as of yesterday.

Comment: You are not telling `graphics` that you are using `dvipdfm`: by default it will assume `dvips`. What happens if you give the driver option?

Comment: To @Joseph Wright : I gave the `dvipdfm` option to `graphicx`. Nothing changed. In fact, I expected this for the following reasons. First, in September, everything worked normally without driver options. Second, everything works fine with TeXLive `dvipdfm`. Third, I will check this once wore tonight, but I am sure that everything still works fine on my laptop, where I made no MikTeX updates since summer.

Comment: Everything works fine here (MiKTeX 2.9, too) with your code and an example image from `mwe` package.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it could not be retraced with a very similar hard- and software setting. Either the original image has a flaw or in the meantime an update of MiKTeX has fixed the error.